# Multiply several sets of columns in the same data.table

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I am looking for a way to multiply several columns of a `data.table` by several other columns in the same DT.  Another post focused on the way to multiply many columns by a *specific* column in the same DT [Multiply many columns by a specific other column in R with data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123098/multiply-many-columns-by-a-specific-other-column-in-r-with-data-table). My question broadens this prior question.

Starting with this DT:

```
DT <- data.table(x1 = 1:5L, y1 = 6:10L, x2 = 11:15L, y2 = 16:20L)

   x1 y1 x2 y2
1:  1  6 11 16
2:  2  7 12 17
3:  3  8 13 18
4:  4  9 14 19
5:  5 10 15 20
```

I want to multiply `z1 = x1 * y1`, and `z2 = x2 * y2` to obtain

```
   x1 y1 x2 y2 z1  z2
1:  1  6 11 16  6 176
2:  2  7 12 17 14 204
3:  3  8 13 18 24 234
4:  4  9 14 19 36 266
5:  5 10 15 20 50 300
```

Here is a brute force way of building the desired DT:

```
DT2[, ':='(z1 = x1 * y1, z2 = x2 * y2]
```

Certainly there must be an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Probably a matter of taste, but you could use `Map` and build some lists to feed it.

```
DT[, c("z1", "z2") := Map("*", list(x1, x2), list(y1, y2))]
```

Expanding to many variables combine with `mget` and `ls`, do

```
DT[, c("z1", "z2") := Map("*", mget(ls(pattern="x")), mget(ls(pattern="y")))]
```

Both of these return the desired result

```
DT
   x1 y1 x2 y2 z1  z2
1:  1  6 11 16  6 176
2:  2  7 12 17 14 204
3:  3  8 13 18 24 234
4:  4  9 14 19 36 266
5:  5 10 15 20 50 300
```

I'll just mention that `mget` and `ls` with patterns can be used to return lists of objects that exist in a particular environment. `ls` searches the parent environment by default, which is the environment of the data.table in which it was called. So in the instance that you have an object named x3 that exists outside of the data.table, you needn't worry: that object is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [R data.table calculate new columns in lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840369/r-data-table-calculate-new-columns-in-lapply) by searching tags "data.table" + "calculated-columns". By extension the answer to my question would be:

```
DT <- data.table(x1 = 1:5L, y1 = 6:10L, x2 = 11:15L, y2 = 16:20L)
FUN <- function(ndx, DT) {DT[, paste("z", ndx, sep = "") := get(paste("x", ndx, sep = "")) *  get(paste("y", ndx, sep = ""))]}
lapply(1:2, FUN, DT)

DT
x1 y1 x2 y2 z1  z2
1:  1  6 11 16  6 176
2:  2  7 12 17 14 204
3:  3  8 13 18 24 234
4:  4  9 14 19 36 266
5:  5 10 15 20 50 300
```

Although this is obviously an answer, it's perhaps understandable how I couldn't find it because I think the title lacks specificity. That said, is there a more straightforward way to approach the question raised here?